# vb.net Entering and retrieving data from a Array

Tags: vb.net

Below is my code to enter data into an array and retrieve the information

Entering the data seems to have no problems but when I click the button to retrieving the information it just presents 0's in the text box.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Array(20) As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim counter As Integer

        For counter = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            Array(counter) = txtEnterMarks.Text(counter)
        Next

        Label1.Text = "omfg"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        For counter = 0 To Array.Length - 1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Array(counter))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Yet another duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17256671/62576 from today. Which school do you all attend that gave this as the homework assignment this week? Please at least do a basic search here before posting a new question. Thanks.

Comment: I have searched every where and cannot find the solution

Comment: I provided a link to at least one place you didn't search when you "searched every where". There is also at least [one other post here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17256889/62576) today that asked the same question (it was closed as being a duplicate of the one I linked). You didn't search very hard; you need to try harder. :-)

Comment: Why can't u just tell me?

Comment: cause i do not know the answer....

Comment: Telling you wouldn't help you **learn** anything.  Have you stepped through your code using a debugger?  Is `txtEnterMarks` a TextBox?  If it is, why are you trying to use it's `Text` property like an array?

Answer (score 0):

Again .. try this different answer

```
Structure Student    
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Mark As Integer
End Structure
```

To save your input in it :

```
Dim StudentsInfo as New List(Of Student)
Dim si As New Student

si.Name = txtEnterName.Text
si.mark = val(txtEnterMark.Text)
StudentsInfo.Add(si)
```

To get value from StudentsInfo

```
txtEnterName.Text = StudentsInfo(0).Name
txtEnterMark.Text = StudentsInfo(0).mark.ToString
```

About preserve it To ListView .. Again .. Try Mr. Google ...